# Handle user abort in Oak router

Tags: file-upload, deno, abort, oak

In Node.js we could use,

```js
  req.on("data", (data) => console.log(`on data: ${data.length}`));
  req.on("close", () => console.log("req closed"));
  req.on("aborted", () => console.log("req aborted"));
  req.on("error", (err) => console.log("req error", err));
```

I've switched to Deno using it for a long time but on a file upload purpose, I need to handle user abort or any kind of network issue to handle the upload data correctly.

This is my current code,

```js
//imports
import { serve } from "https://deno.land/std@0.166.0/http/server.ts";
import { Application, Router } from 'https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts';

...
...

router.post("/upload", async (ctx) => {

  try{
    //get file from multipart form

    const body = ctx.request.body({ type: "form-data" });

    console.log("File upload started");

    const form = await body.value.read({ maxFileSize: 100*1024*1024, outPath: './uploads'});

    console.log(form);

    ctx.response.status = 200;
    ctx.response.body = { path: "file.filename" };

    //get file from form
    if (!form.files || !form.files.length) {
        ctx.response.status = 400;
        ctx.response.body = { msg: "No file provided" };
        return;
    }

    const file = form.files[0];

    //return file path
    ctx.response.status = 200;
    ctx.response.body = { path: file.filename };

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    ctx.response.status = 500;
    ctx.response.body = { msg: error.message };
  }
});


// Start the combined server
console.log("Booting server...");

//socket-io handler
const handler = io.handler(async (req) => {
    return await app.handle(req) || new Response(null, { status: 404 });
});


await serve(handler, {
    port: httpPort,
});
```

The file is stored in disk rather than loading it all in memory. So if user aborts the file upload while it was being uploaded the file gets saved with the available data. So I need to remove this file from disk in this case.

I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: I think the best you can do is read the body yourself via `ctx.request.originalRequest.getBody().body`. I suggest putting in a feature request to oak for exposing the filename on `FormDataReader` via wrapping the Promise, providing the metadata in the error thrown, or providing some auto-delete-partial-reads flag.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. But I had to switch to "Hono" for some reason. Thanks.